# Posting timeout because of bad tags

Tags: support, bug, time-limit

I am currently undergoing a posting timeout on [the IoT site](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tour):

[image]

But I have never posted anything (successfully):

[image]

I think I tried to post a question, but I lacked the rep to create a new tag. I then edited the tags and tried to post again and got the warning.

What is going on?

Comment: You were probably limited by someone else on your network posting.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I thought for registered accounts the time out would be user based and not IP based.

Comment: It's IP-based for all users.